# Seconds left to a specific date

Tags: javascript, html, date, variables

Since there is many solutions to that question I would love to get the **shortest and cleanest** answer.

```
var silvester=new Date("2016/01/01 00:00:00");
```

How can I calculate how many seconds left to that specific date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var time = (silvester.getTime()-Date.now())/1000;
```

Comment: ...by far you are the Winner :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
var silvester=new Date("2016/01/01 00:00:00");
var now = new Date();
var dif = silvester.getTime() - now.getTime()

var Seconds = dif / 1000;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`(new Date("2016/01/01 00:00:00") / 1000) - (new Date().getTime() / 1000)`